# System beep on Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, windows-7

Is it possible to make a beep sound which always plays in the speakers so people can hear it no matter if a headset is pluged in?

I am using c# wpf .Net 4.0 and of course windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a beep sound which always plays in the speakers so people can hear it no matter if a headset is pluged in?

Starting in Windows 7, and in 64-bit versions of previous operating systems, the answer is no, you cannot *always* do a hardware beep. [Larry Osterman explains why](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx).

You can have a beep, but the core functionality moved into the Windows audio subsystem; so it would play through headphones if they are plugged in. As far as I know, there is no way to forcefully do a hardware beep in all cases in modern operating systems.

You can still perform a Beep using [`Console.Beep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hftfeyw.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Declare this somewhere:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32 .dll")]
private static extern bool Beep(int freq, int dur);
```

Then call it like this:

```
Beep(440, 1000); // Concert A, for 1 second
```

Comment: Might just be easier to use `Console.Beep()`. Makes the same P/Invoke call.

Comment: But as vscjones remarks, with Win7 64-bit, you can no longer guarantee the internal speaker will be used to make the sound.  `always plays in the speakers so people can hear it no matter if a headset is pluged in` won't work with either call. Personally, that's a lot less useful than it was before, I agree, but mainly for its Easter Egg value. ;)